# Using Thymeleaf TemplateEngine with Vert.x 3.9

Tags: java, thymeleaf, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am new to Vertx. I am trying to create thymeleaf template engine in my application but it raises this error

> **java: incompatible types: io.vertx.core.Vertx cannot be converted to io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx**

and if I cast **`vertx`** to `io.vertx.reactive.core.Vertx` then I get this error

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl cannot be cast to io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx**

Apart from that database connection is successful and if I remove TemplateEngine line code runs smoothly.

```
package com.firstapp.main;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.common.template.TemplateEngine;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.handler.TemplateHandler;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.templ.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemplateEngine;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.PoolOptions;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.SqlConnection;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  private int server_port = 8080;

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {

    Future<Void> handshake = prepareDatabase().compose(estb -> startServer());
    handshake.onComplete(startPromise);

  }

  private Future<Void> startServer(){
    Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
```

```
TemplateEngine engine = ThymeleafTemplateEngine.create((Vertx) vertx);
TemplateHandler handler = TemplateHandler.create(engine);
```

```
    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("<h1>First App</h1>");
    });

    server.requestHandler(router).listen(config().getInteger("http.port", server_port), result -> {
      if(result.succeeded()){
        System.out.println("Server Started at Port '"+server_port+"'");
        promise.complete();
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("Failed to Start Server");
        promise.fail(result.cause());
      }
    });

    return promise.future();
  }

  private Future<Void> prepareDatabase(){
    Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();

    MySQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
      .setPort(3306)
      .setHost("localhost")
      .setDatabase("vertx_db")
      .setUser("root")
      .setPassword("");

    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(5);

    MySQLPool client = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);

    client.getConnection(connect -> {
      if (connect.failed()){
        System.out.println("Failed to Connect to Database.");
        promise.fail(connect.cause());
      }
      else{
        SqlConnection conn = connect.result();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Database connection successful.");
        promise.complete();
      }
    });

    return promise.future();
  }
}
```

Please guide me If you know how to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you importing the following `...reactivex...` classes from? (i.e. which JAR?):

```
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.common.template.TemplateEngine;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.handler.TemplateHandler;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.templ.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemplateEngine;
```

It looks as if that JAR contains a class `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` which conflicts with the `Vertex` you need to use: `io.vertx.core.Vertx`.

Try removing that JAR from your project (or just from that class, if you need it elsewhere) and then using the following instead (presented as Maven dependencies):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web-templ-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    [others, as needed - e.g. your SQL dependencies...]
</dependency>
```

Then, you should only need to do something like this, to support Thymeleaf templating:

```
import io.vertx.ext.web.templ.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemplateEngine;

...

final ThymeleafTemplateEngine engine = ThymeleafTemplateEngine.create(vertx);
```

And then use `engine.render()` to render your chosen template with its model data.

There is an example on GitHub [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/templating/thymeleaf/Server.java). The example also depends on the `Runner` class which is [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/util/Runner.java).

Comment: I guess there was some conflict so I remove **vertx-rx-java** dependency. Thanks for your help.